# How to show only one object in django admin list view?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

#### Problem

I wish to show only the last row of a `QuerySet` based on the `ModelAdmin`'s `ordering` criteria. I have tried a couple of methods, but none has worked for me.

##### Model:

```py
class DefaultConfig(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    ...
```

##### Attempt 1:

I tried overriding the `ModelAdmin`'s `get_queryset` method and slicing `super`'s result, but I came up with some issues.

I.E:

```py
class DefaultConfigAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    model = Config
    ordering = ('-created_at',)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
         qs = super().get_queryset(request)
         return qs[<slice>]
```

I tried the following values for `[<slice>]`s:

- `[-1:]`: raised an Exception because negative slicing is not supported
- `[:1]`: raised `AssertionError: Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken.`

##### Attempt 2:

I tried obtaining the max value for `created_at` and then `filter`ing for records with that value. I.E:

```py
class DefaultConfigAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    model = Config

    def get_queryset(self, request):
         qs = super().get_queryset(request)
         return qs.annotate(max_created_at=Max('created_at')).filter(created_at=F('max_created_at'))
```

But silly me, that works at row level, so it will only return aggregates over the row itself.

##### Further attempts (TBD):

Perhaps the answer lies in `SubQuery`s or `Window`ing and `rank`ing.

Is there a more straight forward way to achieve this though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to set `list_per_page = 1`?

```
class DefaultConfigAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    model = Config
    ordering = ('-created_at',)
    list_per_page = 1
```

Technically this will still return all `Config` objects, but only one per page and the latest one will be on the first page.

---

Another solution (similar to your "Attempt 2"), which involves an extra query, is to manually get hold of the latest `created_at` timestamp and then use it for filtering.

```
class DefaultConfigAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    model = Config

    def get_queryset(self, request):
         qs = super().get_queryset(request)
         latest_config = qs.order_by('created_at').last()
         return qs.filter(created_at=latest_config.created_at)
```

Comment: At the end I compromised with the `list_per_page`